# Force regression line through origin using sns.jointplot

Tags: regression, seaborn

I am relatively new to python. I have a x-variable and a y-variable plotted against each other using the sns.jointplot function. I know when y is zero, x must also be zero. Is there a way to force the regression line through the origin to satisfy this arguement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! You have a *constrained* linear regression on your hands. You want to find the best linear model in describing your data, right? There are different ways to approach this, but I recommend you try the function `scipy.optimize.lsq_linear` in SciPy. If you're already working in Seaborn this shouldn't be a problem.

This function allows you to input your linear system and a constraint, and then solves the least-squares problem to satisfy the constraint and minimize residuals.